# Public key ( Permission denied, but only when logging as not root)

Tags: unix, ssh, freebsd

I have a Freebsd machine. I can login as root no problem, but when I try to login as any other user it gives an error (I have added 2 users on the vm).

Basically, when I do this

```sh
ssh -p (port number) -i ~/.ssh/id_my_key.pub root@193.229.33.133
```

It works, but when i do this

```sh
ssh -p (port number) -i ~/.ssh/id_my_key.pub user@193.229.33.133
```

It doesn't, and gives me

```
user@193.229.33.133: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems expected, considering SSH will look for your public key in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server (193.229.33.133)

If that same public key was not added to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` (still on the remote server), the same SSH call will fail.

Comment: @JuliusValma You are most welcome. Glad it was helpful.